# Subclassing a vtk style: undefined reference

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I want to subclass a vtkInteractorStyleImage to change mouse behavior on clics. I'm using Qt Creator, and I successfully tried vtkinteractorStyleImage and others.

Here my codes.

## vtkinteractorstylevisor.h:

```
#define VTK_EXCLUDE_STRSTREAM_HEADERS

#ifndef VTKINTERACTORSTYLEVISOR_H
#define VTKINTERACTORSTYLEVISOR_H
#include <vtkInteractorStyleImage.h>

class VTK_RENDERING_EXPORT vtkInteractorStyleVisor : public vtkInteractorStyleImage
{
public:
    static vtkInteractorStyleVisor* New();
    vtkTypeMacro(vtkInteractorStyleVisor, vtkInteractorStyleImage)

    virtual void OnLeftButtonDown();

protected:
vtkInteractorStyleVisor();
~vtkInteractorStyleVisor();

};

#endif // VTKINTERACTORSTYLEVISOR_H
```

## vtkinteractorstyle.cpp

```
#include <vtkinteractorstylevisor.h>
#include <vtkObjectFactory.h>

vtkStandardNewMacro(vtkInteractorStyleVisor)
```

I want to start implementing left click behaviour, but compiling this I get this error:

> vtkinteractorstylevisor.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `vtkInteractorStyleVisor::vtkInteractorStyleVisor()'
>   :-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it.

I forgot to include the implementation of the constructor and the destructor in the .cpp file.

Thanks for the time reading this.